# Routed Events problem - hitting the root UI element before the child element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routedevents

My routed events are hitting the root UI element before the child element.  Is this expected?  How can I have the routed events hit the child element first?

Objective:  If text is typed anywhere other than "custom textbox", put text in "default textbox"

Result: Window_PreviewTextInput is being hit before custom_PreviewTextInput, even if my cursor focus is on "Custom Textbox"

What should I do differently?

---

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        PreviewTextInput="Window_PreviewTextInput"
        >
    <Grid Margin="100,100,100,100">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="default" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="defaultTB" Width="300" Height="50"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="custom" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="custom" PreviewTextInput="custom_PreviewTextInput" Width="300" Height="50"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //goal:  if text is typed anywhere except custom textbox, put text in default textbox
        private void Window_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Keyboard.Focus(defaultTB); 
        }

        //goal:  if text is typed in custom TB, put text there, and end the event routing
        private void custom_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routed Event could be a bubbling or tunneling. You've a tunneling event behaviour.

From MSDN, [UIElement.PreviewTextInput Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx):

> Routing strategy -  Tunneling
>
> The corresponding bubbling event is TextInput.

[Routed Events Overview - Routing Strategies:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

> **Bubbling**: Event handlers on the event source are invoked. The routed
> event then routes to successive parent elements until reaching the
> element tree root. Most routed events use the bubbling routing
> strategy. Bubbling routed events are generally used to report input or
> state changes from distinct controls or other UI elements
>
> **Direct**: Only the source element itself is given the opportunity to
> invoke handlers in response. This is analogous to the "routing" that
> Windows Forms uses for events. However, unlike a standard CLR event,
> direct routed events support class handling (class handling is
> explained in an upcoming section) and can be used by EventSetter and
> EventTrigger.
>
> **Tunneling**: Initially, event handlers at the element tree root are
> invoked. The routed event then travels a route through successive
> child elements along the route, towards the node element that is the
> routed event source (the element that raised the routed event).
> Tunneling routed events are often used or handled as part of the
> compositing for a control, such that events from composite parts can
> be deliberately suppressed or replaced by events that are specific to
> the complete control. Input events provided in WPF often come
> implemented as a tunneling/bubbling pair. Tunneling events are also
> sometimes referred to as Preview events, because of a naming
> convention that is used for the pairs.